# Problema al agregar varios JTree en un JPanel que esta en un JSplitPane - Layout

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo un problema al agregar dos JTree en un panel, les explico, al presionar el JTree se marca en azul todo el ancho que ocupa, quería hacer que ocupe el máximo del JPanel  en el que esta (como un GridLayout), este Panel se agrega a un JSplitPane para cambiar su tamaño, entonces probé hacer un truco que me había funcionado en otra GUI pero con botones:

Agregar un JPanel con BorderLayout, y luego a ese panel agregarle otro JPanel con un GridLayout(0, 1), esto funciona con lo que quiero hacer los botones ocupaban todo el ancho y la altura de estos no se divide entre todo el panel, por lo tanto todos estaban arriba (tambien funciona cuando uso el JSplitPane)

Pero al hacer esto con un JTree se ve que no funciona del todo bien, si bien hace lo que quiero con el JTree (que tenga el mismo ancho que el panel, incluso cuando uso el JSplitPane), al abrir y al volver a cerrar, hay un error que los deja separados

Entonces para terminar de explicar como quiero que se vea, es como cualquier IDE que tiene de estos JTree que colocan uno abajo del otro y ocupan todo el ancho del panel

Ejemplo de Eclipse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Unas imágenes de lo que digo que pasa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien pero...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que decir que he probado otros diferentes Layouts, por ejemplo he usado WrapLayout, lo cual fue mala idea, ya que no ocupa todo el espacio y si agrando el JSplitPane se re-colocan en horizontal.

He usado MigLayout y para cada uno de los JTree hice un "wrap" para que salte a la otra linea, pero aun así tengo el problema que no ocupan todo el espacio del panel y menos si agrando el JSplitPane.

También GridBagLayout lo cual creo que no ayudo de mucho la verdad, quedaba todo en el centro y había que agregar otro panel para que vaya a la parte superior de arriba, pero aun no quedaba del ancho cuando re-dimensionaba el panel con el JSplitPane.

Y la mas "acertada" hasta ahora fue usar dos JPanel como mencione al principio de todo.

Me encantaría que si alguien ya ha trabajado con este tipo de cosas o si sabe como solucionar esto, me pudiera ayudar y muchas gracias.

Prosigo a mostrar el código listo para ejecutar de lo ultimo que intente:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public final class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadLookAndFeel();
        new Main("JTree - Prueba");
    }

    private static void loadLookAndFeel() {
        try {
        
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Main(final String title) {
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(1000, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
        JPanel left = Left();
    
        JPanel right = new JPanel();
    
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        splitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(220);
    
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(left);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(right);
    
        add(splitPane);
    
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel Left() {
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    
        JPanel main_left = new JPanel();
        main_left.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    
        main_left.add(Tree("Caja 1"));
        main_left.add(Tree("Caja 2"));
    
        left.add(main_left, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        return left;
    }

    private JTree Tree(final String name) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode raiz = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name);
    
        DefaultMutableTreeNode colores = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Colores");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rojo = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Rojo");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode azul = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Azul");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode amarillo = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Amarillo");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode verde = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Verde");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rosa = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Rosa");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode celeste = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Celeste");
    
        colores.add(rojo);
        colores.add(azul);
        colores.add(amarillo);
        colores.add(verde);
        colores.add(rosa);
        colores.add(celeste);
    
        DefaultMutableTreeNode figuras = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Figuras");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode ovalo = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Óvalo");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode pentagono = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Pentágono");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode triangulo = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Triángulo");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode cuadrado = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Cuadrado");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode circulo = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Círculo");
    
        figuras.add(ovalo);
        figuras.add(pentagono);
        figuras.add(triangulo);
        figuras.add(cuadrado);
        figuras.add(circulo);
    
        DefaultMutableTreeNode herramientas = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Herramientas");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode alicates = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Alicates");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode calibre = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Calibre");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode serrucho = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Serrucho");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode llaveinglesa = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Llave Inglesa");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode martillo = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Martillo");
    
        herramientas.add(alicates);
        herramientas.add(calibre);
        herramientas.add(serrucho);
        herramientas.add(llaveinglesa);
        herramientas.add(martillo);
    
        raiz.add(colores);
        raiz.add(figuras);
        raiz.add(herramientas);
    
        JTree tree = new JTree(raiz);
        return tree;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin complicarte, usa un solo árbol juntando los nodos raíces de cada caja en una raíz común oculta:

```
    private JPanel Left() {
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    
        JPanel main_left = new JPanel();
        main_left.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    
        DefaultMutableTreeNode raiz = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        raiz.add(TreeNode("Caja 1"));
        raiz.add(TreeNode("Caja 2"));
        JTree tree = new JTree(raiz);
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        main_left.add(tree);
    
        left.add(main_left, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        return left;
    }

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode TreeNode(final String name) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode raiz = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name);
    
        DefaultMutableTreeNode colores = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Colores");
        for( String color : new String[]{"Rojo","Azul","Amarillo","Verde","Rosa","Celeste"})
             colores.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(color));
        
        DefaultMutableTreeNode figuras = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Figuras");
        for( String figura : new String[]{"Óvalo","Pentágono","Triángulo","Cuadrado","Círculo"} )
            figuras.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(figura));
        
        DefaultMutableTreeNode herramientas = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Herramientas");
        for( String figura : new String[]{"Alicates","Calibre","Serrucho","Llave Inglesa","Martillo"} )
            herramientas.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(figura));
            
        raiz.add(colores);
        raiz.add(figuras);
        raiz.add(herramientas);
    
        return raiz;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto funcionó, jamas me lo hubiera imaginado!